# Positioning Overview Map On ArcGIS API for Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am adding an overview Map to the main map by this way

```
  var overviewMap = new OverviewMap({
          map: map,
          visible: true
        });
        overviewMap.startup();
```

which the overview map is poping up at Top-Right

[image]

Can you please let me know how I can I re-position it to left-bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "attachTo" property in the [constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/overviewmap-amd.html#overviewmap1). You have your choice of"top-right","bottom-right","bottom-left" and "top-left". The default value is "top-right"

```
 var overviewMap = new OverviewMap({
     map: map,
     attachTo: "bottom-left",
     visible: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kenbuja, can you also let me know if it is possible to set the size of the overview map as well?

Comment: Thanks I got it from the documentation which  you linked

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered

Comment: sure, I just had to wait to 10 Mins